# Quantity is connected together not summed up

Tags: javascript, session-storage

I have a code where when the add button is clicked, it sums up the value of two objects properties and update it. When you use a "+" button to add an item, it works but whenever the user manually inputs the amount to add, instead of adding them up, it connects it like a string.

Example:

[image]

Where 5100 + 122222 should be 127322. Here's my code snippet:

JS Function:

```
var tobeSaved = store.getters.printCart;

    if(tobeSaved.length){
      if(sessionStorage.length){
        var existingCart = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.cart);
        var size = Object.keys(existingCart).length;
        //console.log(existingCart);
        tobeSaved.forEach(tobeSaved => {
          let obj = existingCart.find(ob => ob.itemID === tobeSaved.itemID);
          console.log(obj);
          if(obj!==undefined){
            obj.itemQuantity+=tobeSaved.itemQuantity;
            existingCart.itemQuantity = obj.itemQuantity;
            let myObj_serialized = JSON.stringify(existingCart);
            sessionStorage.setItem('cart', myObj_serialized);
          } else{
            existingCart.push(tobeSaved);
            let myObj_serialized = JSON.stringify(existingCart);
            sessionStorage.setItem('cart', myObj_serialized);
          }
      })
      
      } 
      else{
        let myObj_serialized = JSON.stringify(tobeSaved);
        sessionStorage.setItem('cart', myObj_serialized);
      }
    }
  }
```

EDIT: Here's the User Input part

```
<div class="product__details__quantity d-flex justify-content-center">
   <div class="quantity">
       <div class="pro-qty">
           <input type="number" v-model="quantity" >
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Edit #2: Added vuex code

```
const store = new Vuex.Store({
state:{
  cartItem: [],
  cartCount: 0
},
mutations:{
    addCart(state, payload){
        this.state.cartItem.push(payload);
    },
    addCount(state, payload){
      state.cartCount+=payload
    },
},
actions:{

},
getters:{
    printCart(state){
        return state.cartItem;
    },
    counter(state){
      return state.cartCount;
    }
}
```

});

EDIT #3. Here's the button that passes the data to vue

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-block" data-dismiss="modal" @click="addCart({
   itemID: selectedUser.id,
   itemName: selectedUser.item_name,
   itemPrice: variant.default_price,
   itemQuantity: quantity
 })">Add to Cart</button>
```

AddCart:

```
addCart: function(cartdets){
    this.quantity = 1;
    var cartItems = store.getters.printCart;
    //console.log(cartItems);
    var filtercart = cartItems.some(function(cart){
      return cart.itemID === cartdets.itemID
    });
    //console.log(filtercart);
      if(!filtercart){
        store.commit('addCart', cartdets);
        store.commit('addCount', 1);
      } else{
        store.commit('addCart', cartdets);
      }
  }
```

Comment: because they are strings.

Comment: `+obj.itemQuantity += +tobeSaved.itemQuantity;`

Comment: Hello @mplungjan, i have tried adding the unary plus operator on each of the variables to be added but it wont save. The console also prints the correct sum

Comment: You are not showing the user input part

Comment: So this is vue. Where is the part where the program reads the quantity from the model

Comment: I'm sorry, im new to vue so i don't quite get you. But I have added my vuex code. I get the cartItem from my vuex state (tobeSaved) and use it inside the function

Comment: I have not yet used vue, but I do not see the word `quantity` anywhere in your code other than in the html so how do you get the string contained in quantity when the user changes it?

Comment: I have edited the question

Comment: Màybe add all RELEVANT code? Where is addCart

Comment: I'm so sorry. Added all the relevant code for the function

Comment: I give up. Please produce a stack snippet or a stackblitz - someone with more vue knowledge needs to see a [mcve]

Comment: Okay. Thank you for your time @mplungjan! It was a big help